# How in django can i insert list view within detail view using mixins

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I want to override get_context_data with containing data from other model.

I have Detail View, and on that website page i want to display list with pagination.

I want to mixing detail view and also few list view, i want to make pagination available on detail page, and i want filtering with .filter() and **kwargs or manual kwargs.

I want inherit list view in detail view, i want to have inheritance of list view within detail view. I want it short.

I want make pagination config withing get_context_data with simple paginate_by = ... Is that possible?

Comment: Class views are good only what they're designed for. If you want a mix, I'd advise to write a function-based view. Alternatively, inherit from View and implement described functionality a methods.

Comment: You might find the [using `SingleObjectMixin` with `ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-singleobjectmixin-with-listview) example from the docs useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyClass, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    context['MyList'] = QuerySet
    return context
```

This adds whatever you want to the context and makes it available in the template.

Comment: what should be instead of QuerySet? Model name or result return of SomeModel.objects.all()

And how about filtering with kwargs or args?

Comment: Yes, SomeModel.objects.all() is your queryset. To filter you can do SomeModel.objects.filter(field=kwargs['field']) if it got passed from urls.py.